# Compute pixel area of a large raster in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, big-data

I want to compute a total area of a large raster dataset using `.reduceRegion()`, but receive the `"Earth Engine capacity exceeded"` Error. Is it possible to overcome it? For example create a vector grid over an AOI, map `.reduceRegion()` over each sell and then sum up the results?

The code is following (also [available on Earth Engine](https://code.earthengine.google.com/bbb0b75788de416cfcff5412d72b8734)):

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[1.0167888602549056, 32.24107677376602],
          [1.0167888602549056, 3.3274515320624296],
          [42.457218547754906, 3.3274515320624296],
          [42.457218547754906, 32.24107677376602]]], null, false);


var dataset = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater');
var selected_data = dataset.select('occurrence').clip(aoi);

var area = selected_data.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: aoi,
      scale: 15,
      maxPixels:1e13
    });

print(area);

Map.addLayer(selected_data, {}, 'Target image');
Map.addLayer(aoi, {}, 'AOI');
Map.centerObject(selected_data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit to resources that you can use on-the-fly and unless that is lifted for you, you can not bypass that. These limits apply when you are trying to view results in the console with print or adding a layer to the map. However, I found a workaround to your issue. Check out the code in earth engine [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e7621b9f355ce9f9def8862bb554106e)

I just created a feature collection with one point feature (can be anything really, it's not important) with the area set as one of its properties.

```
var dummyFC = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([1,1])).set('area',area));
```

Then i just exported the feature collection as CSV to the drive and got a CSV result.

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:dummyFC,
  description:'test',
  fileNamePrefix: 'area_test',
  fileFormat:'csv'
});
```

If you are not interested in running it yourself or don't want to wait for the result of this exact operation. I got the the value 1.3716314113697263E11 (137163141136.97263) as result.